# Combining options in MiniMagick

Tags: minimagick

I'm trying out MiniMagick for some image manipulation but I'm having trouble combining commands. I want to use the `trim` command with a `fuzz` factor.

Calling

```
image.fuzz "30%"
image.trim
```

works perfectly. But my understanding is that the `fuzz` factor will continue to be set for all future commands, which I don't want. Instead I've tried

```
image.combine_options do |c|
  c.fuzz "30%"
  c.trim
end
```

but unfortunately this doesn't seem to do anything (unless I set the `fuzz` factor to 100% in which case it correctly removes every pixel from the image—`fuzz` at 99%, however, does nothing).

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I forgot to add the `+repage` option to `trim`. This works:

```
image.combine_options do |c|
  c.fuzz "30%"
  c.trim "+repage"
end
```