# Cut out background in picture with minimagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

Say I have an image like this: http://shop2.vans.com/wcsstore/Vans/images/products/NKA8MOD1B.JPG

How would I go in order to crop the image so that I can get rid of the background. So, in this case, remove all the extra white color until there is actually the shoe.

I have thought about getting the most outter pixels (top right, top left, bottom right, bottom left) and if the color is the same use that in order to cut horizontally and vertically so that the final image is just "the shoe", with no extra background on the sites.

How can I do that with Minimagick?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt 'trim' give you what you want (the shadow will remain though)?

**edit:** Usage is not obvious and I did not manage to fuzz trim with minimagick quickly. Sorry

**edit2:** In the answer to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754313/combining-options-in-minimagick) code is given that *should* solve your problem.